# Wordpress Site SEO Header

Tags: wordpress, header

One of a wordpress I managed was hacked and the meta data was changed to different language. How do I revert it back to the previous one.

I update the plugins, the themes and the wordpress core but it seems not to be helping out. I just want to change the representation on search engine.

Comment: You have a backdoor plugin or theme that is installed by the hackers. Using ftp or a file manager carefully study your wp-content/plugins folder for plugins that are not actually installed but do have a folder and files. Remove those asap.

Comment: Check / scan your file system or do a complete reinstall if that's an option. Your installation still seems compromised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you have to check where the hacker was coming from. The best way is to restore the website to a previous point and update directly all plugins and themes.

If you can't roll back your website, then you have to check the wordpress instance if there are some various php files that don't fit to the wordpress default installation.

The other solution is to contact your hosting provider to scan your webhosting for suspicious files.